# codeigniter add N in sql Query INSERT unicode text

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, unicode

I am working with codeigniter / SQL. Where I want to insert unicode string with 'N' Prefix the insert. How can I achieve it in regular insert.

**Regular Code:**

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'data' => 'My data'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

**INSERT Trying to Achieve:**

```
INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, data)
VALUES ('My title','My Name',N'My data');
```

Is there any way to achive the above insert instead of manually writing the Query.?

Comment: You should override system DB_driver.php `_insert()` method and make your own that checks every value and use it as converted to N prefix where needed. [Check lines 1396 - 1399](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way to do it.

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'data' => 'N'.'My data' 
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Or, if the prefix needs to more dynamic do this

```
$pre = foo(bar);
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'data' => $pre.'My data' 
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with Unicode using Codeignter 3, driver sqlsrv and I managed to get it working modifying the System/database/DB_Driver.php. Probably there is a better solution out there, it's not beautiful but it's working, just modify the functions _insert and _update.

```
protected function _insert($table, $keys, $values)
{
    foreach($values as $key => $value)
    {
        if(substr($value,0,1) == "'")
        {
            $values[$key] = "N". $value;
        }
    }

    return 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(', ', $keys).') VALUES ('.implode(', ', $values).')';
}




protected function _update($table, $values)
{

        foreach($values as $key => $value)
        {
            if(substr($value,0,1) == "'")
            {
                $values[$key] = "N". $value;
            }
        }

        foreach ($values as $key => $val)
        {
            $valstr[] = $key.' = '.$val;
        }



        return 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.implode(', ', $valstr)
            .$this->_compile_wh('qb_where')
            .$this->_compile_order_by()
            .($this->qb_limit ? ' LIMIT '.$this->qb_limit : '');
}
```

Comment: The solution of ur will not be good whne we use two different db at the same time.. the `N` is used for SQL queries.. can use it in MySQL as well so if we change the core file then this will get affected.

Comment: I like this solution - If you make it dependet of the dbdriver `if ($this->dbdriver == 'sqlsrv')` it wont affect other db connections.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Eggy and Leandro for their suggestion. I use CI 3.1.9 and here is my solution:

```
public function escape($str)
{
    ...
    elseif (is_string($str) OR (is_object($str) && method_exists($str, '__toString')))
    {
        if ($this->dbdriver == 'sqlsrv')
        {
            return "N'".$this->escape_str($str)."'";
        }
        return "'".$this->escape_str($str)."'";
    }
    ...
}
```