# Inserting special characters like ≥ and ≤ into SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I have a requirement to add special characters like ≥ and ≤ into SQL Server database.

I am using the PHP CodeIgniter framework to do that stuff.

The inbuilt CodeIgniter libraries are helping to generate queries like this.

```
 insert into test_table(field1,field2,field3) values ('≥20' ,'≥12' , '≥36');
```

if I execute the above query the data in the database was =20, =12, =36 instead of ≥20, ≥12, ≥36

I have searched a lot on the internet about this I found it will work with a prefix N on each value like below.

```
 insert into test_table(field1,field2,field3) values (N'≥20' ,N'≥12' , N'≥36');
```

it's working but I am generating queries with CodeIgniter libraries is not possible prefix 'N' on the query

Can you please anyone help me on this either insert  ≥ or ≤ values into the database without prefix 'N'
or help me to generate a query using CodeIgniter libraries which can include 'N' before each value.

All my table datatypes are nvarchar

Is any possible to encode the entire table with UTF-8 or something..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198127/codeigniter-add-n-in-sql-query-insert-unicode-text

Comment: I wonder if it wouldn't be recommendable to re-structure your database and just place the values 20, 12, 36 and have a further column indicating 0 or 1 where 0 means <= and 1 >=? see [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)